# Restarting embedded tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat6, maven-tomcat-plugin

I use the embedded tomcat via the maven-tomcat-plugin. In version 6 of that plugin, if i do `mvn tomcat6:run`, the server starts and the `contextInitialized` methods execute **BEFORE** the connector tries to open the port.

No change in code but when I start with `mvn tomcat7:run` the server opens the ports and **THEN** tries to start the `contextInitialized` methods.

Why?

I'm asking because I used the context initialized to find a running tomcat and kill it so that the new instance can take its port. If tomcat fails taking the ports and then checks the contextInitialized methods that doesn't work anymore. Is there another way to redeploy an embedded tomcat without having downtimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tc6 we had the problem that the `contextInitialized`-methode requires informations about the `connector`, for example if `https` and mutual-authentications is used and what users are registred in `tomcat-users.xml`.

Unfortunately theese informations where not available at context-initialization and requests who are incomming before the `users-list`  has been loaded (but after context-init) where rejected.

Thats why we changed this in tc7.

You are using multiple tomcats for some reason (idc), and the solution should better be on a higher level.

> My suggestion: Replace the HTTP-Connector by a AJP-Connector on both tomcats using different ports, install Apache's httpd and switch the tomcats by reload httpd-config.

[AJP details](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/configure-mod_proxy_ajp-with-tomcat/start).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. Do you have a good suggestion for a workaround for the problem I'm having (one server should only be available once everything is initialized properly)?